# Fire jQuery on two events of a select?

Tags: jquery

Okay, let say I have a dropdown menu and two text boxes after it:

```
<select name="service" class="ServiceSelect">
    <option value="5">Hitbox.TV</option>
    <option value="2">Justin.TV</option>
    <option value="4">Livestream</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Twitch.TV</option>
    <option value="3">Ustream.TV</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="value1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="value2" value="" class="value2" />
```

I need to show/hide the value2 field based on what has been selected in the dropdown... I have doing this using some simple jQuery script:

```
$('.ServiceSelect').on('change load', function()
{
    switch ($('.ServiceSelect').val())
    {
        case '1':
        case '3':
            $('.value2').slideDown();
            break;
        default:
            $('.value2').slideUp();
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is that the jQuery is firing perfectly fine on "change". But not when the page initially loads. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` does not have a `load` event, so you should use `window.load` instead:

```
function selectHandler() {
    switch ($form.val())
    {
        case '1':
        case '3':
            $('.value2').slideDown();
            break;
        default:
            $('.value2').slideUp();
    }
}

$(function() {
    selectHandler();
});
$('.ServiceSelect').on('change', selectHanler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the change event on document ready like...

```
$('.ServiceSelect').trigger('change');
```

This will cause the change event handler to run on page load.

You can see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/36RT7/1/